# Where does OpenCL context physically lie?

Tags: opencl

From my understanding, OpenCL context is an abstraction layer. But where does it physically lie (host RAM, GPU memory... or somewhere in the air)?

I just want to understand how it would be possible for the multiple GPUs using the same OpenCL platform can access the memory buffer objects without having to explicitly transferring files in between the host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OpenCL `cl::Context` object, like all Objects of the OpenCL headers, is located in CPU RAM.

The `cl::Buffer` object itself also resides in CPU RAM, but allocates a region of memory in GPU VRAM and stores a pointer to it to allow host<->device data transfer over PCIe.

Multiple GPUs within a platform can - if supported by extensions - access each other's memory through remote direct memory access (RDMA). If supported, a GPU then knows the pointer to the array in the other GPU's memory.